# Definition of a quadratic function

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I can't find a relevant definition of a **quadratic function**. More precisely, in an exercise about numerical optimization, it is said that the function we will focus on is defined as :
\begin{align}
q~\colon~&\mathbb{R}^P\to\mathbb{R}\\
&x\mapsto\frac{1}{2}\left\langle Bx\vert x\right\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^P} - \left\langle c\vert x\right\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^P}
\end{align}
Where $B\in\mathfrak{M}_{P}(\mathbb{R})$ et $c\in\mathbb{R}^P$. It is said that this function is a quadratic function and it is in numerical optimization a very important example since problems involving quadratic functions can be "easily" solved. There is no definition in my textbook, so I wondered if **it was possible to have a little explanation on what exactly is a quadratic function and why this particular function $q$ is a `quadratic function` ?**

Thanks you in advance for any information on this topic.

*Edit 1 while writing this : I think there is also a semantic issue there, since I read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form and I'm note sure if this is related to what I'm dealing with in this exercise
Edit 2 : This exercise is in french and the name used is `fonctionelle quadratique`, so I translated it to english as `quadratic function`. I found no relevant definition using both terms in Google.*

Comment: What you have is a quadratic form $\langle Bx,x\rangle$ and a linear form $\langle c,x\rangle$. In the one dimensional case, you would be dealing with a function $x\mapsto \lambda x^2 + cx$, and in the "higher dimensional" situation, the definition your book is giving is the natural generalization. I have never heard of "quadratic function" used in this way, but it doesn't seem terribly inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm dealing with a sum of quadratic form and a linear form, thanks !